# environ("username") versus advapi32.dll

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I know there are at least 2 ways of retrieving the username in an Access application.

You can use the environ function:

```
environ("username")
```

And you can use GetUsername in advapi32.dll

```
Public Declare Function GetUserName& Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
"GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long)

s = String(l, Chr(32))
GetUserName s, l
username = Left$(s, l - 1)
```

Which one of the above methods is the safest to use? And why?

Perhaps some background info, the applications are used both on the local computers and remote desktops.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Simon has said, Environ variables are open to manipulation, however some people also like to avoid the api calls, if this is the case then this is a simple to follow alternative:

```
Public Function GetUser() As String

    Dim WNet As Object

    Set WNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

    GetUser = WNet.UserName

    Set WNet = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: +1 except I would skip the `Set Nothing` statement because WNet will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables can be set and unset by anyone, go missing and whatnot, and these cases tend to be difficult to reproduce if anyone even thinks of it as a source of errors.

I'd definitely go with advapi.