# Filename containing a cell value and the user name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master.xlsx sheet with multiple columns.

I create a .csv. It contains column E from master.xlsx.

```vb
Sub generatecsv()
'
' generatecsv Macro
'

'
    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\JONDOE\Documents\FixedText_" _
      & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ".csv"
    Windows("Miluna_1.1.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

I'd like the filename in the format:
**DATE**-**USERNAME**-**FIXEDTEXT**-**ValueFromTheCellD2(in master.xlsx)**.csv

My macro will create a filename:
**FixedText_24-Feb-2023**.csv.

I can work on the order of the variables in the filename myself.

I don't understand how to get
the username, since this file will be used by multiple users;
and how to get the D2 value from master.xlsx.

To get a username I know there is the `Environ("Username")` function, but I don't understand the usage.

Can I put everything in the `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename` or do I create variables for the username, the D2 value, fixedtext and the date and refer to these variables?

Comment: Regarding the user name, this example could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8988438/17017616

Comment: `FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & "-" & Environ("USERNAME") & "-" & FIXEDTEXT & "-" & Workbooks("Master.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value & ".csv"`. It's quite long, so maybe split it into a few variables e.g. `FolderPath`, `NameDate`, `UserName`, `FixedText`,  `Filename`...

Comment: Thank you very much, it's much clearer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple job to do, refer to the comments of @VBasic2008 above and what you've done.

```
Sub generatecsv()
    Dim d2Value

    d2Value = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value

    Columns("E:E").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\FixedText_" _
      & Environ("USERNAME") _
      & "-" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY") _
      & "-" & d2Value & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Windows("Miluna_1.1.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

By adding 2 points:

1. `FileFormat:=xlCSV` to save as CSV text, by default it's a binary Excel doc.
2. `ActiveWorkbook.Close` to close the created csv Sheet.